# Path Dependency in Scala

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

```
  trait B {
    type MyInnerType
    def foo: MyInnerType
  }      
  object B1 extends B {
    type MyInnerType = Double
    val foo = 3.0
  }

  trait A {
    type MyInnerType
    val b: B
    def foo(x: b.MyInnerType): MyInnerType
    def bar(y: MyInnerType): Unit
  }
  object A1 extends A {
    type MyInnerType = Int
    val b = B1
    def foo(x: b.MyInnerType) = 1
    def bar(y: MyInnerType) {}
  }
  object A2 extends A {
    type MyInnerType = String
    val b = B1
    def foo(x: b.MyInnerType) = "a"
    def bar(y: MyInnerType) {}
  }

  val as = Seq(A1, A2)
  as foreach { a => a.bar(a.foo(a.b.foo)) }   // wrong, a.foo(a.b.foo) infers to Any
```

However, if `a.foo` does not take parameters, everything works perfectly and `a.foo` infers to `a.MyInnerType`. It also works if I cast `.asInstanceOf[a.MyInnerType]`. Any explanations?

Comment: I don't know the full answer (and I gotta split), but I think I know where the real problem is.  It's the inferred type of `as`.  Change it to `val as: Seq[A] = Seq(A1, A2)` and you should be good to go.

Comment: `:Seq[A]` Did not helped

Comment: My fault - pasted the same code. Works when annotating them

Comment: Seems to be a weird problem of type inference. Anyway that's a solution and thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running scala 2.9.1 and on the REPL I get this for `as`:

```
scala> val as = Seq(A1, A2)
as: Seq[ScalaObject with A{def foo(x: Double): Any; val b: B1.type; type MyInnerType >: java.lang.String with Int}] = List(A1$@6da13047, A2$@7168bd8b)
```

However, when I change it to `val as:Seq[A] = Seq(A1, A2)` I get:

```
scala> val as:Seq[A] = Seq(A1, A2)
as: Seq[A] = List(A1$@6da13047, A2$@7168bd8b)

scala> as foreach { a => a.bar(a.foo(a.b.foo)) }
```

Sometimes (all the time) scala has trouble inferring types, so you have to annotate what you want. I go to the REPL often to find out what's really going on.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I also believe that scala is doing some over-inference here: I don't want `x` to be inferred as `Double`, since it depends on instances. Anyway the problem is solved. thanks!